# Storing an array over group members

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the case:
User creates group `cars`.
User2, user3, user4 and user5 asks to join `cars`.
User approves user2, user3, user4 and user5

Should I have a table like this:

```
Leader (userid)
, description
, image
, Users (array { userid1, userid2, userid3, userid4 } )
```

and

```
user_groups 
username, groupid, status
```

Which would look like

```
User2 1 0
```

status 0 means user2 is pending on group invitation, and status 1 means he's in the group. Then if someone visit users2 profile, I query

```
select * from user_groups where username=$username
```

Is this the cleanest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be wiser to create a table for Users, that way you would be able to add more information to the users if you wanted. Then create a Groups table, with the groupid, description, image, status, so on. Finally, create a table to map them together, using two foreign keys - groupid from Groups and userid from Users - as the new primary key. Here I would also put a binary value for if they are the group leader or not.

Comment: I went with Group(id, name), group_members(group_id, user_id, status and leader) Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 1):

Arrays never, ever are the cleanest way. What is wrong with simply doing

```
User(UserID, Name)
Group(GroupID, LeaderUserID, Name)
UserGroup(UserID, GroupID, Status)
```

Or, to steal from DevinFalgoust, alternatively:

```
User(UserID, Name)
Group(GroupID, Name)
UserGroup(UserID, GroupID, Status, IsLeader)
```

Comment: I went with Group(id, name), group_members(group_id, user_id, status and leader) Thanks for the reply though!